# How to find the location of an element in an array?

Tags: java, arrays, location, element

How would I go about searching for a location of an element through user input.  So for example, the user is asked "What element do you want to search for in the array [21.1, 1.3, 81.1]?", the user inputs "81.1", the location is given to them.

This is the code I attempted to do that with:

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Scanner;



public class LowestTemperature
{
    public static void main( String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        double[] temps = arrayFromUrl("http://learnjavathehardway.org/txt/avg-daily-temps-atx.txt");

        System.out.println( temps.length + " tempatures in database.");

        double highest = -1, lowest = 9999.99; 
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 

        for ( int i = 0; i<temps.length; i++)
        {
            if ( temps[i] < lowest ) 
            {
                lowest = temps[i];
            }
            if ( temps[i] > highest)
            {
                highest = temps[i];
            }
        }

        System.out.print( "The lowest average daily tempature was ");
        System.out.println( lowest + "F (" + fToC(lowest) + "C)" );
        System.out.print( "The highest average daily tempature was ");
        System.out.println( highest + "F (" + fToC(highest) + "C)" );   
    }

    public static double[] arrayFromUrl( String url ) throws Exception
    {
        Scanner fin = new Scanner((new URL(url)).openStream());
        int count = fin.nextInt();

        double[] dubs = new double[count];

        for ( int i = 0; i<dubs.length; i++)
            dubs[i] = fin.nextDouble();
        fin.close();

        return dubs;
    }

    public static double fToC( double f)
    {
        return (f-32)*5/9;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I quickly took a shot at modifying your existing code. 
In short, I added a method which simply scans the users input for a double,
I then take that double and loop through the array you provided.
If it finds a match, it prints out at what position of the array the element was found.
Hope this helps!

```
package lowesttemperature;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class LowestTemperature
{
    public static void main( String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        double[] temps = arrayFromUrl("http://learnjavathehardway.org/txt/avg-daily-temps-atx.txt");

        System.out.println( temps.length + " tempatures in database.");

        double highest = -1, lowest = 9999.99; 
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 

        for ( int i = 0; i<temps.length; i++)
        {
            if ( temps[i] < lowest ) 
            {
                lowest = temps[i];
            }
            if ( temps[i] > highest)
            {
                highest = temps[i];
            }
        }

        System.out.print( "The lowest average daily tempature was ");
        System.out.println( lowest + "F (" + fToC(lowest) + "C)" );
        System.out.print( "The highest average daily tempature was ");
        System.out.println( highest + "F (" + fToC(highest) + "C)" ); 

        double term = searchTerm();
        for (int i = 0; i<temps.length; i++)
        {
            if(temps[i] == term){
                System.out.println("The term you searched for is at position " + i + " in the array"); 
            }
        }
    }

    public static double[] arrayFromUrl( String url ) throws Exception
    {
        Scanner fin = new Scanner((new URL(url)).openStream());
        int count = fin.nextInt();

        double[] dubs = new double[count];

        for ( int i = 0; i<dubs.length; i++)
            dubs[i] = fin.nextDouble();
        fin.close();

        return dubs;
    }

    public static double searchTerm(){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a double: "); 
        double input = scan.nextDouble();
        return input;
    }

    public static double fToC( double f)
    {
        return (f-32)*5/9;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though this sounds like homework, you've at least attempted most of it so far.

This should work:

```
Scanner inputScan = new Scanner(System.in); 
double input = inputScan.nextDouble();

int pos = 0;

for (int i = 0;i < temps.length;i ++){
    if (temps[i] == input){
        pos = i;
        break;
    }
}

System.out.println("Temperature matching your search: "+temps[pos]);
```

You might want to add to it to handle if the search doesn't match anything or if there are multiple results.

Comment: You should `break;` out of the loop once double is found.

Comment: Haha, no it actually isn't homework. The homework was to add the "highest average temperature." I'm just interested in knowing how to do it.

Comment: Why use a boolean when you can simply use the `break;` statement?

Comment: Better to use a flag than a break in my opinion. But in this case a break was more effective. Thanks.

Comment: `int pos = -1;` = `not found`

Comment: I think the poster can add that himself.

Answer (score 0):

Advice in future. Variables `highest` and `lowest` assign to the first element of the array. Then it is universal. What if the temperature is less than -1 degree?

I know that it is not connected with the problem.

Comment: I had a look and I already knew that wouldn't be possible before hand.  So I just did -1.  I would obviously just crank down the number to -9999, lol.

Comment: I thought about solution for any numbers. No by giving different constant to the min, max, but universal solution. Nevermind:).

Answer (score 0):

Consider using an `ArrayList<Double>` instead of a primitive array `double[]` to store the temperatures and then use an `indexOf(Double d)` method wich returns the index of the first occurrence of the specified value in the list (or -1 if does not contain the value).

Also, construct a TreeSet from this ArrayList (`TreeSet tree = new TreeSet(temps);`) that constructs an object containing the temperatures sorted and then use `tree.first()` and `tree.last()` methods to get the lowest and highest temperatures.